# Is it possible to plot the tabuler representation of a dataframe from DataFrames.jl using Makie.jl?

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

I would like to plot the tabular representation of a dataframe from the DataFrames.jl package using Makie.jl or using any of the other plotting libraries in Julia. Another option would be to save the dataframe as an image.

Comment: That's a bit of an unusual thing to do, could you explain what exactly you need this for? DataFrames uses PrettyTables.jl as its display backend, and PrettyTables can export tables in html and latex format. I'm not aware of any way to directly make an image from a table (although I guess you could get a pdf from the html easily)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm computing various metrics of a trajectory in a dynamical system and I'm producing a plot constituted of some subplots like that a phase space plot, a recurrence plot etc. I'd like to display some of the scalar metrics in a table format as it will be easier for me to parse than a bar chart of something similar.

Comment: @NilsGudat actually I think that Sal has a good idea. Suppose you run some parameter sweep for numerical experiments and generate a multi-page PDF or a bunch of images with let's say 100 plots. It would be quite convenient to see each parametrization directly on the plot rather than look it up in an external table.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `annotate!`, you just need to remember that inbuilt `monospace` font in Plots.jl does not nicely support all Unicode characters so you need to use a simpler table formatting (markdown formatting will actually look good and nice). On the other hand Makie seems to support system fonts so you can get nicer formatting.

```
using DataFrames, PrettyTables, Plots
pyplot()
df=DataFrame(a=1:5,b='a':'e',c=rand(5))
io = IOBuffer()
pretty_table(io, df, tf = tf_markdown, show_row_number = true)
str = String(io.data)

plot() # do whatever plotting you need
annotate!(0.5, 0.5, text(str; family="monospace", pointsize=8))
```

[image]

And here is the same example with Makie:

```
using CairoMakie, Makie

f = Figure()
ax = Axis(f[1, 1])
io = IOBuffer()
pretty_table(io, df)
str = String(io.data)


text(5,5, text=str, font="Consolas", textsize=14)
```

[image]